# How do I stop Maven from looking in all remote repositories for pom files of dependencies that are already installed to my local repository?

Tags: maven-2, maven

In my Maven2 project, I am depending on a jar (mule-core-2.2.1.jar) that has two dependencies which are located in remote repositories but which do not have pom files defined.  So my mvn command is initially able to pull down the jars, BUT the problem is that every single time I run a mvn command, it checks every single repository for both of these poms.  Can I tell mvn not to check for these poms since I already have the jar in my .m2 directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent Maven 2 from searching remote repositories for specific local depedencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560180/how-do-i-prevent-maven-2-from-searching-remote-repositories-for-specific-local-de)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about just creating a POM? You could install the POM-less artifacts using

```
mvn install:install-file \
-Dfile=sample-artifactA-2.2.1.jar \
-DgroupId=org.mule.or.wathesle \
-DartifactId=sample-artifactA \
-Dversion=2.2.1 \
-Dpackaging=jar \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

Once the artifact has a POM Maven shouldn't need to check anymore.

Comment: This is not ideal but I think is the best available option.  I went with mvn deploy:deploy-file instead so that other developers can also benefit without having to run the command themselves.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.or.wathesle</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
  <version>YOUR_MULE_VERSION</version>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>sample.group</groupId>
       <artifactId>sample-artifactAB</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is how I would exclude the artifact.  I need the artifact; the problem is that the person who deployed the artifact to their repo didn't provide a pom.  So maven checks for the pom every time it is called (note that it doesn't check for the jar since I have that in my local repo).  What I want is to tell Maven to not check for the pom since I have the jar.